# Scalaz `Tag.apply`: How does it work?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monoids

Hi I am studying the Advanced Scala book, and I have some trouble understading this piece of code from scalaz source:

```
object Tag {
  /** `subst` specialized to `Id`.
    *
    * @todo According to Miles, @specialized doesn't help here. Maybe manually specialize.
    */
  @inline def apply[@specialized A, T](a: A): A @@ T = a.asInstanceOf[A @@ T]

  // ...
}
```

How can it work? `a.asInstanceOf[A @@ T]` should fail with ClassCastException shouldn't it?

An example of usage is:

```
Multiplication(2) |+| Multiplication(3)
```

In this case `a` is an Int how can it be converted to a `@@[Int, Multiplication]` (`Tagged[Int, Multiplication]`)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is "Advanced Scala book?" I didn't find any such book on Google.

Comment: It is book from underscore: http://underscore.io/training/courses/advanced-scala-scalaz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works because of *erasure*. `@@` is a purely type-level construct, meaning it has no runtime representation.

The type `A @@ T` is an alias for the type `AnyRef{type Tag = T; type Self = A}`. And since `Int` can be safely cast to `AnyRef` (under the hood this is done via casting a `java.lang.Integer` to a `java.lang.Object`), this works just fine.

The additional structure `{type Tag = T; type Self = A}` only exists at compile-time, so it has been completely erased by the time the JVM does the cast.

Why do this? The purpose of `@@` (which I pronounce "qua") is to create a new type from an old one, without incurring a runtime overhead.

If we used, for example, `case class Multiplication(value: Int)`, this allows us to treat `Multiplication` as distinct from `Int`, but it creates an actual `Multiplication` object at runtime.

If we used a type alias like `type Multiplication = Int`, then there is no runtime overhead. But now `Multiplication` is indistinguishable from an `Int`, which is not what we want.

The type `Int @@ Multiplication` prevents us from using a value of this type directly as an `Int`, even though it really is just an `Int` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks now it makes sense. It is basically a pre Scala 2.10 value class.

Comment: This is strictly more general than value classes, since the type `A` in `A @@ T` can be any type whatsoever, not just a subtype of `AnyVal` as in value classes.

Comment: @Apocalisp: No, value classes can be used to wrap types which are not a subtype of AnyVal, like `class Foo(val underlying: String) extends AnyVal`. But value classes can result in runtime overhead in some cases, see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html . On the other hand, the tagged type approach will always result in runtime overhead for primitive types (`Int` becomes a JVM `int` but `Int @@ Foo` becomes an `Integer`).